# Regular Expression replace ' - ' with '-'

Tags: php, regex, replace

I'm not sure if this is a good place to ask questions like this, but I'll give a try :)

I need help with RegExp. I'm trying to write expresion which will replace ['any number of spaces' + '-' + 'any number of spaces'] and replace it simply with '-'. So it's all about removing spaces if in the middle is placed '-'.

So for example:

```
'something -  something' -> 'something-something'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any number is `*` so just:

```
/ *- */-/
```

PHP:

```
preg_replace("/ *- */", "-", "fooo   -    bar ");
```

JS:

```
"fooo   -    bar ".replace(/ *- */, "-");
```